# Sync setup question: will Android, Outlook 2010, Gmail, calendar and contacts sync?

Tags: sync, 2.2-froyo, outlook

my previous phone was a windows mobile 6.5 from HTC. so I had it linked to my computer (windows 7 x64 pro) and it used windows mobility center to sync with outlook 2010. everything was fine. I also added Gmail by IMAP in outlook.

but now I have this awesome brand new HTC Desire with Android 2.2 (Froyo) so it asked for my Google account. Now I ended up with contacts in outlook, phone and Gmail. calendar in outlook and Google Calendar and I have HTC sync and `Google Cal` sync and I don't know what the best setup is. anybody an idea?

I'd like to have the same in my outlook contacts as in my Gmail, Google Cal, phone etc. so I'd like to sync everything with everything and could use some help. because I have contacts in outlook that are not in Gmail and people on my phone which are not in Gmail etc. and since I am an android n00b it's kinda hard to get myself an ultimate sync setup with outlook 2010 and my phone and Gmail stuff

**Edit:** as pointed out in the answers, I should *NOT* sync my phone with outlook, but should sync outlook to Gmail. Google has a calendar sync tool, which is great, **but does not sync the contacts**. No I've found `KiGoo` but I don't trust them yet. Does anybody recommend a good preferably free and/or open source application for syncing outlook 2010 with Gmail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android syncs to Gmail, Contacts, and Calendar nearly effortlessly. It seems like in your case it's Outlook that is the problem child. Do you need to sync contacts with Outlook too? If not, a one-time export/import from Outlook to Gmail should meet your needs.

I would say have Outlook sync with Google and have the phone sync with Google. Syncing the phone to Outlook too will probably duplicate data and/or leave gaps in your data.

Comment: I agree.  Your phone will always sync with Google.  Setup Outlook to sync with Google too and leave the phone <-> outlook sync out all together.  Outlook to Google sync has been something people have been working on for years so it seems to me that those solutions are going to be more refined than the newer android/outlook solutions.

Comment: Agreed as well. In fact just take Outlook out of the picture all together. It is not providing any necessary functionality here, unless JP has other email accounts in Outlook. In which case just add those email accounts to the Mail app on the phone and stop syncing between Outlook and phone.

Comment: @Webs: I have about 10 email-accounts setup in outlook, so i still need outlook for my profession. i need to sync outlook to gmail. contacts and calendar. but google only has a calendar sync. what is the best app to use?

Comment: just read about KiGoo but I don't trust them yet. http://www.kayxo.com/ anyone good experience with a good (free/open source) app for syncing the google cal + contacts with outlook 2010?

Comment: Syncing Outlook and Gmail isn't a question for the Android Enthusiasts. I suggest either http://webapps.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com.

Comment: @Al E. i thought it was android related since i'd like to have everything in sync. but i have posted the question back to it's origin at http://superuser.com/questions/189287/sync-setup-question-outlook-2010-gmail-calendar-and-contacts

Comment: @JP what we are trying to tell you is don't sync Outlook to your phone. Just have Outlook connected to your gmail account, and your phone connected to your gmail account. Then all should be well right? Then for when you need contacts and such you can do the occasion HTC sync and manually push items over.

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for a way to sync my x10 with outlook and found this link, it's called my phone explorer
http://www.hackitz.ca/droid/android_contact_sync_outlook

works good, and it's free